# Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, arn

I am from India and I am travelling to Latvia for the first time to study there. I have a D visa (long stay). I have a layover of 13 hours in Sweden. Will they allow me to go outside of the airport. Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

Flights Sweden-Latvia are effectively domestic, so you will clear immigration in Sweden, not Latvia. And yes, you can enter Schengen anywhere on your D visa.

Have your connecting boarding pass ready to present to the Swedes on request.